# linking a document to another document- quick parts label missing data

Tags: hyperlink

I have a quick parts label that contains version number, review date and document ID. When i use the document id to create a link in another document, it works thought the quick parts is missing the actual values. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: to clarify my question, i am creating procedures in the form of flowcharts (these will be on sharepoint). What i would like to do is reference other documents on SharePoint with the flowchart by pasting the the document ID from the properties. This works fine and opens the linked doc from within the flowchart. The problem then is that when the link opens and you view the document the label that i have inserted via quick parts is empty: Version:{_UIVersionString} Document ID: {Document ID Value} Review Date: {ReviewDate}.This needs to be complete for printing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link to know the details of Document Id set and function which you need to be know:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/450288/Document-ID-Feature

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. Try to include the good parts from the links in your post, and only use the links as a source to more information. If the links break your answer will be of no help to future readers